# Naming convention for methods which create an instance of an object A from another object B

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Is there a naming convention for methods which create an instance of an object A from another object B?
For example:

```
public static A convertFrom(B b) {
    return new A(b);
}
```

I've seen many names like `of`, `valueOf` and similar.

Comment: The latest version of Java seems to favour the use of `of`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-

Comment: If you need a lot of those functions, consider the context: adapter classes (for instance turning a ResultSet into a Table model), wrapper classes, extension pattern classes (eclipse Adaptable/Adapter, used for associating a new class's instance wtih an old class's instance, decoupled).

Comment: @ortis They've also used `from`. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor- . Maybe `of` is used when you want to fill attributes with those arguments and `from` when you want to create the object based on the argument.